# How to implement Shopware plugin providing both frontend and backend functionality?

Tags: plugins, frontend, backend, shopware

I want to implement a Shopware plugin, that provides some changes to the frontend as well as a backend interface. Is that possible or will I need to implement two separate plugins? In case of separate plugins, how could I make sure that both plugins are installed and updated together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is only important to put them into their directory.

Controllers/backend
Controllers/frontend

there are also two different classes to extend.

the backend controller extends Shopware_Controllers_Backend_ExtJs 
the frontend controller extends Enlight_Controller_Action

Answer (score 0):

Found it my own: You can add both frontend and backend controllers, so you're not restricted to one of these areas...